# Show that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}⁡\frac{1-\cos⁡(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2 )x^2y^2}$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus

This is a question from Advanced Calculus for Math Major.

I tried many different curves to show that the limit is not the same, and I tried the polar coordinates but nothing important appeared.

I need at least a hint to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Put $x=y$ and use the fact that $1-\cos \theta \sim \theta^{2}/2$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Consider $x = y$, from whence you get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1 - \cos(2x^{2})}{2x^{6}} = \frac{\sin^{2}(x^{2})}{x^{6}} = \frac{1}{x^{2}}\times\left(\frac{\sin(x^{2})}{x^{2}}\right)^{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

We can find a lower bound for it. Use $x^2y^2 \le \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{4}$. Thus put $t = x^2+y^2 \implies f(t) \ge \dfrac{1 - \cos(t)}{t^2}\cdot \dfrac{4}{t} \to +\infty$ for $t \to 0^{+}$. Hence the limit is actually $+ \infty$.